# fancyvrb always creates new page

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, fancyvrb

I'm having trouble using the `facyvrb` package. I have the following code:

```
\section{My section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single] 
...lots of code...
\end{Verbatim}
```

However, pdflatex constructs a whole page just containing the subsection header, the rest of the page empty, and then, on the next page starts the verbatim section. How can I tell the Verbatim part to be exactly under the subsection, something like the [H] command with floats on figures?

Comment: @Timo --- Please edit your question and add a complete example code that reproduces the problem you describe.

Comment: that is not possible with the package `fancyvrb` which you already load, it can have page breaks. Only the `BVerbatim` environment is put in a box (note the preceding B). As Ian wrote, give more informations ...

Comment: `listings` is based on `fancyvrb` ...

Comment: Does this happen *always* or only when the subsection title falls near the end of a page?

Answer (score 3):

I can't see any problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\section{My section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single,framerule=1mm,framesep=3mm,
   rulecolor=\color{red},fillcolor=\color{yellow}]
Verbatim line.
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single,framerule=1pt,rulecolor=\color{blue}]
...lots of code...
\end{Verbatim}

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]